# Clone only allocated space of ubuntu server vm

Tags: partitioning

I need your help. I have ubuntu server on vmware ESXI and I need to clone not all disk but only allocated space. It looks like this:
[gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1igj.png)
[lsblk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbHFQ.png)
[fdisk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIq1l.png)
[image]

[image]

[image]
I need some space on new vmware host so I don't want to clone/import all existing disk.

Comment: What OS & release?  Your first picture shows a Debian logo, which is **not**  what I see on my Ubuntu system.

Comment: Ubuntu server 22.04. First picture comes from gparted live cd.

Comment: When I try to resize disk (even by 1 GB) by editing VMDK file I'm getting: **Volume gropu "ubuntu-vg" not found. Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg**

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did it!

- I attached a new disk with 854GB capacity and partitioned it exactly like existing disk 931GB (of course without unallocated space);
- from live CD I used dd command to clone partitions from existing disk to the new one;
- from live CD I used gParted to flag first partition on the new (854GB) disk as "bios_grub"

and voila! Disk have 854GB capacity and system works!